# Second 4K monitor color text shadows with nvidia kernel

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I have installed the Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu. I have laptop and a secondary 4k monitor. With nvidia drivers enabled the text on screen appears like this (there are blue shadows on the right side of letters):

[image]

Before using the Nvidia drivers I had the default Nouveau driver and color wise everything was fine, but I had other problems that the Nvidia driver solved.

How can I get rid of these shadows?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu Bionic 18.04